# Center everything on my page with CSS - menu bar, tables, etc

Tags: html, css

I found some free source code online for a nice menu bar that I like. It came with its own stylesheet which worked fine, but it jacked up a lot of the vertical alignment on my existing site. I want the menu bar and all tables centered on every page--simple. But because of this new stylesheet, everything is kinda centered, but not quite, and sometimes it's way off center.

I can fix any page, case by case, by playing around with margin-left in various elements, but this is tedious, and whenever I add a menu item, or put 2 tables side by side, etc, the horizontal alignment gets all jacked up again. I'm looking for a simple, universal way to center my menu bar and tables so that when menu items are added or removed, or tables get wider or placed side-by-side, all the centering stays correct.

First, a visual:

[image]

As mentioned, I can get everything to align perfectly only if I change styles on a page-by-page basis and tweak it differently on each page. I'm looking for a global solution.

The body tag has a width set:

```
<body style="width:720px;margin: 50px auto">
```

The menu source instructions said I have to set a width on body, which I've never done before on other web pages. If I don't do it, all the alignment goes way off. It seems ideal to not have to set a body width, I'm guessing that's causing problems.

The HTML for the menu bar looks like this:

```
<ul id="nav" style="margin-top:-95px">
    <li><img src="images/RefSlot_Menu.png" onclick="location.href='index.html'" title="RefSlot Home Page" style="cursor:pointer;width:119px;margin-right:78px;margin-left:10px"></li>
    <!--<li><a href="index.html" title="RefSlot Home Page" style="font-family:Collegiate;font-size:25px;color:#000000;margin-right:20px;margin-left:10px">RefSlot</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="Organization.php">Organization</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="AddUser.php">Create New Member</a></li>
            <li><a href="OrganizationUsers.php">Your Members</a></li>
            <li><a href="Sites.php">Sites</a></li>
            <li><a href="ArchivedGroups.php">Archived Groups</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:addGroup()">Create Group</a></li>
    <li><a href="Profile.php">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS on top-level UL:

```
#nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 6px 0;
    background: #777D85 url(images/gradient.png) repeat-x 0 -110px;
    line-height: 100%;

    border-radius: 2em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
}
```

CSS on each LI:

```
#nav li {
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0 0 8px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
```

What can I do to force my content to center? Currently I'm having to tweak around with margin-left on BODY or TABLEs, etc, different on each page. Thanks in advance.

Working example: http://www.refslot.com/_stackdemo.html

Comment: if you have an actual link to some general aspects that would help as I like to mess around. @juventiner answer might work, but I'm not sure if that is exactly what you want.

Comment: @SweatCoder could you share a working demo on fiddle? - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Working example: http://www.refslot.com/_stackdemo.html

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your css file:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or change your body tag like this:

```
<body style="width: 720px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention 1 more style attached to body: margin: 50px auto -- the 50px brings the menu down from the top which is needed. So the margin 0 auto doesn't really work.